# Convert Time to Long format in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I have an input box where I am displaying the time in the following format: HH:mm AM/PM.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myTime" required/>
```

I am doing this using the date filter in AngularJS -

```
$scope.myTime = $filter("date")(new Date(), 'shortTime');
```

I want to pass this time to rest layer, which needs this time in the long format. Is there any way to do that in Angularjs?

PS- I would like to do it without using Moment.js, if possible.

Comment: check this out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: (new Date()).getTime() returns the long for the given date

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/prash/Cp73s/323/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Cp73s

Comment: @VladimirM how can I do it on $scope.myTime variable? I tried doing like $scope.myTime.getTime() but it failed with the error - "$scope.myTime.getTime is not a function"

Comment: @PandiyanCool Thanks for the jsfiddle. I can see that you are using filter to show the date and time in different formats. But how can I get the long value of only time "HH:mm AM/PM" using these filters?

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik Thanks for the link. But I am already able to get the current date using "shortTime" filter. My problem is that I want the long value of this time now. Is there any way to that? Have I missed something while reading the document?

Comment: @VladimirM i tried doing it like-- new Date(myTime).getTime() but it returned NaN value.

Comment: @blu3 see the answer I just posted. You will have to parse the time value, since it is not a Date() format.

Comment: @VladimirM Thanks for the answer. It is very clear and really helped in solving my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, lets imagine, you have a string, containing "HH:mm" (btw, HH means that your hours range from 0-23, so ap/pm is kinda redundant there). To get your local date with that time into the long format you do:

```
// parse the time string
var time = "22:30".split(":")

// create a new date 
var x = new Date();

// adjust time to target time
x.setHours(time[0]);
x.setMinutes(time[1]);

// finally, get the long version
x.getTime();
```